# OpenGL/SDL2 double depth buffering

Tags: c++, opengl

the big picture: I'm writing a renderer for volumetric models using a splatting approach (with C++, OpenGL and SDL2). I've got a multi-resolution data structure (an octree). While the camera is moving rendering is done at a resolution that runs in real time. As soon as the camera stands still, rendering at higher resolutions is done (= iterative refinement).

The problem: Since rendering during refinement can last multiple seconds, I need to cancel it once the user decides to change the camera position. Not a problem regarding the color buffer, I use double buffering and simply don't switch it. But I have to clear the depth buffer before rendering, so when I cancel the rendering run, the information in the depth buffer is lost. The thing is, I need the depth information in another part of my renderer.

My question: What is the best strategy in this case? Backup the depth buffer? Or is there a way to do depth double buffering out of the box using OpenGL and SDL2?

Answer (score 0):

You can render the depth information to a frame buffer to back it up

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

This way you can implement the double depth buffer thing yourself